# Easy Jquery rotator creating 2 gallerys next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm currently facing the problem that I can't configure the Jquery rotator from 
[Easy Jquery Auto Image Rotator](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html) and script source  [Google jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js)

I gave the second gallery a different class and doubled the js script.
Then I replaced all the class and selector names with the second gallery.
But then only one of the gallery works and i'd like to have a solution which covers 
both galleries with on function.

Also i've tried to use only onefunction and put both div ids into the (id) sections
-> Didn't work. Now both layers are placed above each other and I can't move them 
by giving them float:left and float:right.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

**These are the divs:**

```
<div class="rotator">
  <ul>
    <li class="show"><img src="img/screenshots/screen1-big.jpg" alt="pic1" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen2-big.jpg" alt="pic2" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen3-big.jpg" alt="pic3" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen4-big.jpg" alt="pic4" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="gallery">
  <ul>
    <li class="take"><img src="img/screenshots/screen3.jpg" alt="pic1" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen2.jpg" alt="pic2" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen4.jpg" alt="pic3" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/screenshots/screen1.jpg" alt="pic4" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>  


</div>
```

**These are the div classes**

```
/* rotator in-page placement */
div.rotator {display:none; float:left; width: 451px;}
/* rotator css */
div.rotator ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
div.rotator ul li { position:absolute; list-style: none;}
/* rotator image style */   
div.rotator ul li img {width:451px; height: 313px;}
div.rotator ul li.show {z-index:500;}

div.gallery {display:none; float:right; width: 451px;}
/* rotator css */
div.gallery ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
div.gallery ul li { position:absolute; list-style: none;}
/* rotator image style */   
div.gallery ul li img {width:451px; height:313px;}
div.gallery ul li.take {z-index:500;}
```

**Function 1 for the rotator div**

```
    function theRotator() {
        //Set the opacity of all images to 0
        $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

        //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
        $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

        //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds

        if ($('div.rotator ul li').length > 1) {
        setTimeout('rotate()', 6000);
    }
    }

    function rotate() { 
        //Get the first image
        var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')? $('div.rotator ul li.show') : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

        if (current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

        //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
        var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

        //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order

        //var sibs = current.siblings();
            //var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
            //var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );


        //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
        next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

        //Hide the current image
        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function(){setTimeout('rotate()', 6000);}) .removeClass('show');

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {      
        //Load the slideshow
        theRotator();
        $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
            $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
    });
```

**Function 2 for the gallery div**

```
function theGalley() {
        //Set the opacity of all images to 0
        $('div.gallery ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

        //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
        $('div.gallery ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

        //Call the gallery function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds

        if ($('div.gallery ul li').length > 1) {
        setTimeout('rotate()', 6000);
    }
    }

    function rotate() { 
        //Get the first image
        var current = ($('div.gallery ul li.take')? $('div.gallery ul li.take') : $('div.gallery ul li:first'));

        if (current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.gallery ul li:first');

        //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
        var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('take')) ? $('div.gallery ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.gallery ul li:first'));

        //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order

        //var sibs = current.siblings();
            //var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
            //var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );


        //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
        next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('take').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

        //Hide the current image
        current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function(){setTimeout('rotate()', 6000);}) .removeClass('take');

    };

    $(document).ready(function() {      
        //Load the slideshow
        theGallery();
        $('div.gallery').fadeIn(1000);
            $('div.gallery ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Typo

Well, first and foremost, you are defining your `function` as **`theGalley`**, but when you call it, you are calling it **`theGallery`.**

I assume the **2nd** slideshow is the one not working???

I don't want to dive deeper if I don't need to, but fix the typo and let me know if that resolves the issue.

**I will post more after you update with a response.**

#### Update:

#### Working Live Site: http://sinsysonline.com/rotate/image-rotator.html

Regarding: `function(){setTimeout('rotate()',` in your rotate function (callback at the end), you have `two functions` called `rotate`. This is a big *no-no* with writing `Javascript`.

**Let's pretend your `classes` were called (for the sake of readability):**

- rotator
- rotator2

**You can make it functional as such:**

```
function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});
    $('div.rotator2 ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});
    $('div.rotator2 ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    if ($('div.rotator ul li').length > 1) {
        setTimeout('rotate()', 1000);
        setTimeout('rotate2()', 1000);
    }
}
function rotate() { 
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')? $('div.rotator ul li.show') : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function(){setTimeout('rotate()', 1000);}) .removeClass('show');
};
function rotate2() {    
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div.rotator2 ul li.show')? $('div.rotator2 ul li.show') : $('div.rotator2 ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator2 ul li:first');

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator2 ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator2 ul li:first'));

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('show').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000, function(){setTimeout('rotate2()', 1000);}) .removeClass('show');
};
$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();
    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
    $('div.rotator2').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator2 ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```

Comment: I've corrected the typo and it's still not working. 
The rotators are next to each other the left one has everything showing in the Sourcode but does not rotate the images.

<strong>See the screenshot here:</strong>
[Link]http://i58.tinypic.com/2lj5oh3.jpg

Comment: Added working example. If you feel this is an acceptable answer, please select the green checkbox next to the voting arrows.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicholas, that made it working.
Have a wonderfull easter weekend and bless you!

Comment: I'm just facing a new issue now.

After a while (approx. 20 sec.) the rotators beginns spinning faster and then seems to get stuck between 2 images at the end...

I'm sorry i'm just no JavaSript developer and currently working the first time with such animations.

Comment: K, looks like you should run it with two functions. Rewriting answer above.

Comment: that did it, thanks once more Nicolas. Really appreaciate your help!